# how to get performance index in JMeter programmatically

Tags: jmeter

we have the application performance index available in the JMeter dashboard.

how can we programmatically get the performance index values to analyze this data further?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand your question.

But if you want to get the data from HTML in a usable way, you should know that JMeter also generates in the output folder a JSON file called statistics.json that you can parse easily to automate.

Comment: yes i checked that file but the file does not have data for application performance index(APDEX) which I was looking for

Comment: you can make an enhancement request at jmeter bugzilla https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html so that it is added.